# Extend woocommerce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have wordpress child theme, and in it I can extend woocommerce by creating folder of following structure:

```
/wp-content/themes/theme-child/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/*.php
```

But the problem is that I wan't to extend something located in

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-plugin/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/*.php
```

By first approach I can override `woocommerce` files, but how do I do it for `woocommerce-plugin`?

Comment: you want to override woocommerce-plugin or override woocommerce into the "woocommerce-plugin"  , can be more specific.

Comment: I want to override files located here `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-plugin/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/*.php` without changing orignal files. So to make some form of child theme/plugin

Comment: If you just need to edit /single-product/add-to-cart/ *.php files, inside your active theme folder, make a `woocommerce` folder with a `single-product` subfolder. Then inside this subfolder copy entire `add-to-cart` folder located in `plugins/woocommerce-plugin/templates/single-product/… After that is better to keep only customize php files templates (easier when woocommerce templates get updated).

Answer (score 1):

To override woocommerce templates without changing anything in woocommerce plugin folder, you need to copy entire `templates` folder *(located in woocommerce plugin)* to your active child theme folder and rename it `woocommerce` *([**see here**](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/))*. Like this the active woocommerce templates are now in your child theme folder and you can customize them…

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by calling the `wc_get_template` hook, just tell where the files should be overriden:

```
add_filter('wc_get_template', 'plugin_wc_templates', 10, 5);
function plugin_wc_templates ($located, $template_name, $args, $template_path, $default_path) {
    $plugin_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
    $newtpl = str_replace('woocommerce/templates', $plugin_path. '/templates', $located);
    if ( file_exists($newtpl) )
        return $newtpl;
    return $located;
}
```

Remember to print `$plugin_path` variable to make sure that path is being generating ok.